# how to plot a diagonal plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to create a diagonal plot in python, I am working off an example that works but I am getting a key error message. The code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'https://library.startlearninglabs.uw.edu/DATASCI410/Datasets/JitteredHeadCount.csv'
headcount_df = pd.read_csv(filename)
headcount_df.describe()

num_cols = ["TablesOcc", "ablesOpen", "HeadCount", "TablesClosed", "DayNumber"] 
sns.pairplot(headcount_df.loc[:, num_cols], hue='DayOfWeek', 
             palette="seismic", diag_kind="kde", 
             size=2).map_upper(sns.kdeplot, cmap="Blues")
```

I am getting a key error messaging `KeyError: 'DayOfWeek'`and

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
```

I am not sure why it is not working this time. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you passing the 'DayOfWeek' column to pairplot?

Comment: Typo too - `"ablesOpen"` should be `"TablesOpen"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

filename = 'https://library.startlearninglabs.uw.edu/DATASCI410/Datasets/JitteredHeadCount.csv'
headcount_df = pd.read_csv(filename)
headcount_df.describe()

sns.pairplot(headcount_df, hue='DayOfWeek', 
             palette="seismic", diag_kind="kde", vars=["TablesOcc", "TablesOpen", "HeadCount", "TablesClosed", "DayNumber"],
             size=2).map_upper(sns.kdeplot, cmap="Blues")
```

Comment: Do you have much experience with Jupiter Notebook? I am having issues with the code not computing. The code is simple so should only take a few seconds to complete but this is the second time I have had an issue with the code not computing in this book. any ideas why that may be?

Comment: It seems like pairplot is just an expensive function and it probably doesn't help that there are 175,000 entries in your csv file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612434/what-are-ways-to-speed-up-seaborns-pairplot